# Enterprise Data Auditing

Tags: entity-framework, audit

Our current enterprise solution is a ASP.NET MVC application driven by the Entity Framework.  There are a couple links on how to hook into the change events for auditing.  I'm not really interested in this.

I'm interested in enterprise level auditing architecture.  Those of you with the enterprise level battle wounds, what has been your auditing solutions?  Do you serialize objects in databases in a framework.  Are you setting up database triggers to audit tables?  Do you use a separate database all together so your audit growth doesn't affect your app database?  I'm interested in the tried and true solutions here.  I know there's options in our technology choice (EF) but I'm interested in the foundation first.

Links would be very appreciated.

Comment: Let me also make another important note.  We are passionate about being able to go back and seeing old data in the application.  This is where we feel that persisting serialized objects is helpful (not only recording the deltas).

Comment: The distinction between one database and multiple databases is somewhat artificial. Databases can have multiple filegroups, and tables can have multiple partitions. You can effectively treat a single database as if it were many databases, and a single table as if it were multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen several solutions, but my favorite one was simplicity itself:

- Create audit tables that mirror each source table, adding a few extra columns to track the date and type of change (insert, update, or delete if you support it) and the user making the change. Remove all constraints and indexes (unless you expect to be doing a lot of searches).
- Inside of the table update logic (we used procedures, but there's no reason it couldn't be done with an OR/M or other persistence layer, given the appropriate hooks), write to both the source table and the audit table.

This has numerous benefits, but the biggest one (in my opinion) is not having to worry about or write all the code to manage the transactional integrity of the paired write operations in the client.

Comment: No stored procs here with the EF decision though we can hook into the changes meaning we could make this happen on persistance.  So basically this is a mirror of the app tables in a seperate db?

Comment: That's right, except in the same db, such that you would have tables like "Employee" and "EmployeeHistory" alongside each other. (Though Craig Stuntz' comment above pertains here.) In retrospect, there's no reason for me to say it assumes stored procedures, so I've edited that text away.

Comment: Does that mean that the one database is having to write everything twice? Have you noticed any impact on throughput from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any links, but in the system that I have the joy of maintaining here at the day job.  We have a single audit table, that basically stores the following information.

TableName, PrimaryKeyValue, ModifiedColumn, OldValue, NewValue, ChangeUser, Change Date

Now, this works great for audit speed, in our code, we have a common interface for auto-implementing the audit logging, but from a "review" standpoint, it isn't the "fastest" way to get the information back out.  (Granted we have not actually done anything to need to look at the audit log...)

Comment: So basically one growing table, is this in the same DB?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, also we don't have any indexes on the table at the moment either.  It is in the same DB for some, but there is another version that adds a "Database" column and is stored outside.

Comment: How do you handle changes to relationships?

Comment: Could you explain how you handle deleted records

Answer (score 2):

We recently had to solve this same problem in our enterprise. We were required to be able to revert back to prior versions too.

We ended up auditing the business entities rather than the tables in sql. We basically serialize the records in the DB and keep track for the changes that are made from one version to the next. This approach allows us to retreive previous versions into the business entities and then revert back by calling the same save operations. This functionality to revert back will be shifted on the applications responsibility because it must be solved here otherwise our service might need to know about too many details about the participating applications. Serivce Operations to retrieve records by versions, by dates, view history, and of course to audit changes are provided. Its an opt-in approach for different application groups and different entities within (not everything in the DB needs to be auditted so why do that).

We then build a lightweight website that talks to the service and can display all the versions. We built a mechanism to show the additions/updates/deletions to compare between versions (really cool ui representation) this allows users to see who changed what and when. The service can send back a link to the url to view the versions of an entity. This allows our webaps + winform/wpf apps to launch a browser so users can see the changes.

Maybe I can package this up and provide if anyone is interested....

Comment: So you're taking the EF objects and serialising those then storing them in an audit table/database of their own? How do you handle parent-child relationships?